# Swift 3 - Sharing pinned locations in Map Kit

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, mapkit, core-location

I am currently working through the Ray Wenderlich book called iOS Apprentice, specifically the tutorial called MyLocations. In this tutorial, the user of the app is able to get the coordinates and address of their current location, categorize the location (i.e. a landmark), add a description, and then pin the location to a map.

I am curious if it is possible to create a back-end, perhaps through Firebase, where the pinned locations are able to be shared with other users of the app. In other words, if I opened the map to see my previously pinned locations, I would also be able to see other users' pinned locations and the description that they added when they categorized the location.

Is this possible? If so, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes you could do this in Firebase or CloudKit. In CloudKit you could create `CKRecord`s containing co-ordinates, a category and a description. Then your app could query the `CKContainer` and retrieve the public `CKRecord`s and display them.

Comment: Sounds good. Unfortunately, I'm only a few months into learning iOS development and I am clueless regarding how to go about doing what you mentioned. I appreciate the feedback. Any more advice?

Comment: The best suggestion is to write some code to learn how to interact with Firebase. You task would be pretty trivial to do using Firebase as a backend to store user coordinates. Those could be live and interactive and for example, a user could receive an event when another user is close to them. For now though, this question is much to broad to answer in this forum. Please review these great reads [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)